# Why do I get weakref in pandas reassignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to get rid of rows whose index `isin` the list `["A", "C"]`.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame({"Col": [1,2,3,4]}, index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

> ```
>    Col 
> A   1 
> B   2 
> C   3 
> D   4
> ```

Now I put reassignment:

```
df_test = df_test[~df_test.index.isin(["A", "C"])]
```

I'm trying to understand the following result.

```
df_test._is_copy
(* <weakref at 0x11d14a4a8; to 'DataFrame' at 0x11d0dbac8> *)
```

1. why do I get `weakref` copy here?
2. Is it a right way to eliminate rows whose indexes are in the given list? Should I use `.loc[:,:]` on the left or `.copy()` on the right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe .drop is the preferred method (and doesn't generate your copy error). I'm not sure why though

`df_test = df_test.drop(['A', 'C'])`

[image]

Comment: Please translate your answer to real code and prevent posting images.